How to correctly use NextJS Server Side Rendering?
I'm currently developing my first NextJS application, which get some data from a database and then show it on the front-end.
My main concern is about the server side rendering, for context, I want to implement a match history based on data from the database, all the data fetching could be done by the server, but i didn't got exactly how to do it.
The main ideas where: Use getServerSideProps or return a async component that would call a async function to get  the data.
async function getPlayerData(params: Array<string>) {
  return 1;
}

async function page({ params }: { params: { player: string } }) {
  const playerInfo = decodeURI(params.player).split("-");

  return <div>{await getPlayerData(playerInfo)}</div>;
}

My main idea was to do something like this, but i don't know the specific details about this implementation.
Can I call the data directly from the database on the getPlayerData? Since it's called only on the server side, or should i do a API Route for the specific database operation and then fetch the API endpoint during the mount?
Can I use both the client side and server side fetching for the match list? Pre-render 20 matches for example, and then give the option for the user to append more 20 matches with a API call.
I also have a Tanstack React Table that make me do the same questions, currently is working by fetching on the client side, the data remains the same, only being filtered by the table, can I delete the API route and get the data directly from the database on the first mount of the component?
